# Sikuli multiple scripts batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sikuli

I'm trying to create a batch in Windows 7 that will open at least two Sikuli scripts in sequence. I've tried using the solutions found here and couldn't get them to work. This is the batch command I've used:

```
cmd /C C:\path\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r C:\path\Sikuli\all.sikuli
cmd /C C:\path\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r C:\path\Sikuli\sikuli_test.sikuli
```

I've also tried:

```
start /i /b /wait C:\path\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r :\path\Sikuli\all.sikuli
start /i /b /:\path\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r :\path\Sikuli\sikuli_test.sikuli
```

The first Sikuli script executes but the second one does not. The problem seems to be within Sikuli IDE opening in cmd, which once it initializes doesn't allow any more commands in the batch to execute as Sikuli's monitoring process takes over the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

`start /wait` will wait for the executable to exit before continuing. Remove the `/wait` switch and batch will proceed to your second command.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
cd C:\SikuliX   && runScript.cmd -r C:\path\Sikuli\all.sikuli
cd C:\SikuliX   && runScript.cmd -r C:\path\Sikuli\sikuli_test.sikuli
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I have two batch files to call the sikuli files ("Dummy1.sikuli" and "Dummy2.sikuli"). 
And then I have a 3rd batch file that will call all other batch files. 
Sikuli opens by using the command window, and this way both .sikuli files have a command window.

My examples are all located in: 
C:\Dummy

Files located here: 
Dummy1.sikuli 
Dummy2.sikuli 
Dummy1.bat 
Dummy2.bat 
RunDummies.bat

Dummy1.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Run Dummy1.sikuli
C:\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r C:\Dummy\Dummy1.sikuli
```

Dummy2.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Run Dummy2.sikuli
C:\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r C:\Dummy\Dummy2.sikuli
```

RunDummies.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /C Dummy1.bat      
start cmd.exe /C Dummy2.bat
```